# Why does not accept messages?

Tags: c#, android, c#-4.0, xamarin

Under WinForms works and so no.

In the future, I want to show, somehow, all posts in a row. But until this stage is not reached, because now even a single message is not accepted.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public string mess;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        StartListening ();

        Button bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        bt.Click += delegate { start();};
        // Get our button from the layout resource, and attach an event to it
    }

    public void start()
    {
        TextView text = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);

        StartListening();
        text.Text = mess;
    }

    private readonly UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(45000);

    public void StartListening()
    {
        this.udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }

    public void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 45000);
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);

        mess = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        StartListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Can you detail what your issue is and what your asking? Also include an debug information.

Comment: Flagged. Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question and tell us what you are looking for.

Comment: The exact question - why this code does not display a message?

Comment: The issue is that text.Text is set before your message is received. Either set the text value in Receive() or create an event when mess is populated.

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov: have you debugged the `start()` method? Does the call of `FindViewById()` deliver the correct control and is there a message in the `mess` variable indeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug your code you'll see what happens when! So try this and I trust you'll be surprised how easy it is to solve your problem.

Anyway, the way you set the message is timed incorrectly. Try this code instead. It removes the message state (functional programming) and sets the message after it has been received.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private readonly UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(45000);

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        StartListening();
        Button bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        bt.Click += delegate { StartListening(); };
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        this.udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }

    public void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 45000);
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        DisplayMessage(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
        StartListening();
    }

    public void DisplayMessage(string message)
    {
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar option.
Neither he nor your not work unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov: Would you please debug this solution? If it doesn't work I suspect `FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1)` doesn't do its job as you expect. What is kind of certain is that the code in your question is incorrect because displaying messages is done at the wrong time. Again, debugging will help you answer this question - we can't debug here, you can.

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov: nothing is needed, just debug and check what happens when `DisplayMessage()` is called.

Comment: Before this method did not get it.

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov: Please clarify your comment. I don't understand it. To sum up the response: Please tweak your code as per this answer, then debug with a breakpoint in `DisplayMessage()` and anywhere else you want. Debugging through your code will likely give you answers to your questions.

Comment: If debugging step by step, doesn`t reach to  DisplayMessage() .
After calling StartListening() returns to  bt.Click += delegate { StartListening(); }; doesn`t reach to Receive

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, well, this is good news as you know now that the `Receive()` is not being called. If you follow debugging principles you will find the cause of the issue. Keep in mind, we're not here to help with debugging. We're here to help solving programming challenges.

Comment: I understand it perfectly, but debugging is not helped me find the cause.